# Selenium Extract the ID of an element found via text in Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, cucumber

I have a set of Cucumber tests I wish to execute using selenium and Chrome. Most of my test work fine. I am currently trying to parametertize one particular step so that anyone using the Test can simply name the elements they want and the test will find them.

The Cucumber test looks something like this:

```
When I go to the "Inventory" / "Inventory" application

And I search the "Description" field for "a"
```

I was able to get the when statement to parameterized very easily, but the And Statement is giving me a bit more trouble. The page itself has several sets of tables with a consistent id scheme The xpath for the header with the word "Description" looks like this:

```
//label[@id='m6a7dfd2f_ttrow_[C:2]_ttitle-lb']
```

and the input field has this xpath

```
//td[@id='m6a7dfd2f_tfrow_[C:2]-c']/input
```

For reference the immediate next input field, located below the label room, has this xpath

```
//td[@id='m6a7dfd2f_tfrow_[C:3]-c']/input
```

So each label and input field have the same id scheme and only the number following "c:" seems to change. That number is the same for both the label and it's corresponding input value. I would like to some how scan the page for the word "Description" and extract the ID of the element associated with it and then truncate it down to the number. I already have variables set up to hold the rest and it would hopefully as follows:

```
@When("^I search the \"([^\"]*)\" field for \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_search_the_field_for(String searchField, String searchItem) throws Throwable {
String baseinputXPath = "//td[@id='m6a7dfd2f_tfrow_[c:";
String endinputXPath = "]-c']/input";
String elementNumber = "The return of some sort of method based on searchField";//TODO
driver.findElement(By.xpath(baseinputXPath + elementNumber + endinputXPath)).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(baseinputXPath + elementNumber + endinputXPath)).sendKeys(searchItem);
driver.findElement(By.id("search_button_img")).click();
```

If there is a way to pull out that number based only on the description text, that would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a xpath to search for the WebElement with word 'Description' in a label tag.

```
"//label[text(),'Description']" or "//label[.='Description']" or "//label[contains(text(),'Description')]"
```

Use the `getAttribute("id")` to get the id.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I can now make this dynamic by passing in a variable for description. Thank you.